# Need to use code to get the last column in my data rather than use the column letter

Tags: vba, excel

My code currently uses the last column (in this case column o) searches all the rows in that column and clears the whole row which have a certain value in column o of that row. Please can I get some help to modify my code to automatically choose the last column rather than use the letter "o" or the value "15" of that column as for other spreadsheets it may not always use column o. See my working code below:

```
Sub edit_wb_1()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim value As String
    Dim OldDate, NewDate As String

    OldDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 0), "ddmmyy")
    NewDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "ddmmyy")



    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashah\Downloads\HistoricSummary.xls", 0)

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Historic Summary Page 1")

    lastRow = ws.Range("o" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        value = ws.Cells(i, 15).value ' Column O value.

        ' Check if it contains one of the keywords.
        If (value Like "-") Then
            ws.Rows(i).ClearContents
        End If
    Next

    wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\ashah\Documents\TPS Shapes\TMB " & NewDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at [this: linky](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) It's got 5 different ways detailed for finding both the last row and the last column in a worksheet

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance (still learning the ropes) - but I'm still stuck, as that link provides ways to find the last column (how would I utilise that in the range). In my scenario, if you see my code, I simply need the code to instead of use column O, use the last column. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Sub edit_wb_1()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim lastColumn as Long
    Dim value As String
    Dim OldDate, NewDate As String

    OldDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 0), "ddmmyy")
    NewDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "ddmmyy")



    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashah\Downloads\HistoricSummary.xls", 0)

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Historic Summary Page 1")

    lastRow = ws.Range("o" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' gets last column in the first row (where you usually have headers so should be populated...

    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    value = ws.Cells(i, lastColumn).value ' last col instead of Column O value.

    ' Check if it contains one of the keywords.
    If (value Like "-") Then
    ws.Rows(i).ClearContents
    End If
Next

wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\ashah\Documents\TPS Shapes\TMB " & NewDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The below alterations to your code should work.

I have made an assumption the row 1 is a header row.

I have also changed the variable name `value` to `StrValue` as `value` is used by built in Excel VBA functions and could cause ambiguity.

```
Sub edit_wb_1()
Dim wb          As Workbook
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim lastRow     As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim Strvalue    As String
Dim OldDate     As String
Dim NewDate     As String

OldDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 0), "ddmmyy")
NewDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "ddmmyy")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashah\Downloads\HistoricSummary.xls", 0)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Historic Summary Page 1")

'This assumes row one is a header row
i = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    Strvalue = ws.Cells(i, 15).value ' Column O value.

    ' Check if it contains one of the keywords.
    If (Strvalue Like "-") Then
        ws.Rows(i).ClearContents
    End If
Next

Set ws = Nothing

wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\ashah\Documents\TPS Shapes\TMB " & NewDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
wb.Close 0

Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```